# Deserialize an object in scala after zipAll Seq

Tags: scala, deserialization

I used `zipAll` method with two Seq, merging the two lists, so now trying to access the objects from the merged list

```
val foosList = listFoos
val barsList = listBars
val mergedList = foosList.zipAll(barsList,"missing","dupe")
```

Now I am trying to access the respective objects from the merged list, like

```
var someField = mergedList.head._1.someField // the "mergedList.head._1" is of type java.io.Serializable
```

How do I retrieve my object values??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the solution I was searching for was

```
mergedList.seq.head._1.someField
```

And also using `zip` instead of `zipAll` as I am trying to map a 1-to-1 relations